# hr breaks :nth-child() selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There has to be a simple explanation for this. But in my opinion it should work as intented.

We are working with the Bootstrap 3 CSS framework. On a page, we have the following code:

```
<div class="promoties-overzicht">
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Now when I do `.promo-row:nth-child(odd)` to style the odd promo-rows with a gray-ish background color. It styles every promo-row. When I remove the `<hr>`'s the CSS is applied correctly. 
I might be wrong, but since I use the class `.promo-row` in the CSS selector, it should only look at these elements to declare if it is an odd row or not. Why are the `<hr>`'s seen as elements with the same class?

Comment: It should be possible to style the div's and replicate the effect of the hr using padding, margins and a border, so you can probably dispense with the breaks, if that helps.

Comment: In this case I would like to keep the hr tags in there :)

Comment: Peripherally related, although I didn't code it I was getting "nth-child" styling applied to successive `<hr>` elements, giving alternating line weights (as viewed in Firefox). I chased this behavior down to the use of fractional, e.g. `1.5px`; `0.2rem;` -- not integer, e.g. `1px;` -- values for the "height" of the `<hr`> defined in my CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.promo-row:nth-child(odd)` does not mean "the odd `.promo-row` child elements," it means "the `.promo-row` elements that are *also* odd child elements." This is just like `.foo.bar` means elements that have both `foo` and `bar` classes.

CSS doesn't have the concept of "nth matching this selector." If your structure is as regular as you show, you can still use `nth-child` but allowing for the `hr` elements by using `:nth-child(4n+1)`:

```css
.promoties-overzicht .promo-row:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="promoties-overzicht">
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: The `:nth-child(4n+1)` worked out perfect. And thanks for the explanation. I'll never forget :D Strange that this was the first time I ran into this though...

Answer (score 0):

It's because the coun of odd is broken by the presence of `<hr>` (or another block). It applies to all the `.promo-row` following others `.promo-row`.

Considering the following example:

```
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>

<hr>
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
<hr>
<div class="row promo-row">.. other contents ..</div>
<hr>
```

The css will apply only to the third `.promo-row`, not to the last one because they have a `<hr>` block between them ( it restarts the count )

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN's nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.

Since `<hr/>` are siblings of your `promo`s, they are also counted by that pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

nth-child count all child and not only the child which have .promo-row class, you shoumd try something like

```
.promo-row:nth-child(4n)
```

It select a child every four child (so one cycle with 2 .promo-row and 2 hr) and it begin with the first child